What am I missing from FFTW's advanced interface to make it the same as the basic interface for a test case?
I am using a legacy CFD code that uses a pseudospectral solver, and ultimately I want to update the code with better FFT algorithms, so I'm currently learning the interface of FFTW3 in Fortran. I have a 3D velocity array from the DNS code in various forms to test the FFTs and make sure I'm transforming things correctly.
Currently, I have a 3D array which is physical in the first dimension but spectral in the other two dimensions. My goal is to do a 2D transform on this array to get the 3D physical values, and I'm stuck trying to figure out what is wrong with my current code.
I have successfully done a 2D transform of one single plane of my 3D input array using fftw_plan_dft_c2r(), but when I tried to iterate over the planes, I got bad results (I assume because of something happening with the destroyed input vector, but when I tried to preserve the input, I got a segmentation fault).
I figured I might be better off using the advanced interface to do multiple DFTs on the planes, using fftw_plan_many_dft_c2r(). So the first test case is what I'm showing in the code provided, and that's doing a transform of a single 2D plane with both methods. For certain parameters, I believe these routines should be identical. The expected output is an mz x mx array of a constant value around 150. The basic interface routine indeed gives me this result, but the advanced interface gives me something that looks like
   9576957.89326171       -6100449.91245205        4941.42749753309     
  -2029633.19975117        378.904251844637       -1219266.13730242     
   1476.66846120109       -868929.573548530       -20.9026499204410     
  -676593.055185564        450.197926313034       -552121.186219578     
  -425.926031798779       -467648.354118945       -220.256552425897     
   ...

I'm really not sure what else I could even change. Out of curiosity, I played around with {i,o}stride, {i,o}dist, and {i,o}nembed, but nothing seemed to get me closer to the right answer.
Code below:
program fftw_test

    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    include 'fftw3.f03'

    ! Grid sizes
    integer, parameter :: nxh = 128, nz = 128
    integer, parameter ::  mx = 384, mz = 192

    ! FFTW Variables
    type(C_PTR) :: plan2,plan3
    complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), dimension(nz,nxh) :: u_phys

    complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), dimension(nz,nxh)     :: u1_2d,u3_2d
    real(C_DOUBLE),            dimension(mz,mx)      :: u2_2d,u4_2d

    integer(C_INT), dimension(2) :: msize_2d = (mx,mz)
    integer(C_INT) :: rank, howmany, idist, odist, istride, ostride

    ! ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ !
    ! ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ !

    ! Create FFT plan (before initializing variable)
    print *,'Create FFT Plan(s)'
    rank = 2; howmany = 1; ! 1 2D c2r transform on an (mz) x (mx) array 
                           ! (msize_2d is flipped because of column-major arrays)       
    idist = 0; odist = 0;  ! Unused since howmany = 1
    istride = 1; ostride = 1; ! Array is contiguous in memory (I think?)

    plan2 = fftw_plan_dft_c2r     (rank, msize_2d,u1_2d,u2_2d,FFTW_ESTIMATE)

    plan3 = fftw_plan_many_dft_c2r(rank, msize_2d,howmany,       &
                                   u3_2d,msize_2d,istride,idist, &
                                   u4_2d,msize_2d,ostride,odist, FFTW_ESTIMATE)

    u_phys = (0.0,0.0)
    u_phys(1,1) = (150.569261744544,1.136868377216160E-013)  

    u1_2d = u_phys ! temp storage
    u3_2d = u_phys ! temp storage
    
    ! Execute FFTs
    print *,'Execute FFTs'
    call fftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan2,u1_2d,u2_2d)
    write(200,*) u2_2d

    call fftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan3,u3_2d,u4_2d)
    write(201,*) u4_2d

    ! Destroy FFT plans
    call fftw_destroy_plan(plan2)
    call fftw_destroy_plan(plan3)

end program fftw_test

EDIT: I updated the code to explicitly define the grid size variables and the sample spectral array to be transformed. However, for some reason the 2D transform no longer works for me despite not changing anything in the code from my previous verification.

Unfortunately, I don't know fortran at all but "when I tried to preserve the input, I got a segmentation fault" is most probably a sign of that you've managed memory wrong or passed parameters the wrong way. If you would like to get to the root of that segfault, I think you'll get a lot of information by compiling with -g -fsanitize=address,undefined and then watch the output when you rerun the program. It's usually spot-on when bughunting in C and C++ and I hope it'll work for fortran too.

@TedLyngmo Yes, my initial method of dealing with that bug was not worrying about it and trying something different instead. Maybe this would help elucidate the underlying problem, although not without its own problems. Apparently I can't run address sanitizer on my platform because of some parameter in some file I'm not allowed to change.

Try to make a [mre] that does not require any data files and other modules.

@VladimirFГероямслава I updated the question to address that. However, as I mention in my comment, the code no longer works at all for me (segmentation fault at fft plan execution), so perhaps I have more debugging to do than I thought.

Well integer(C_INT), dimension(2) :: msize_2d = (mx,mz) is almost certainly wrong and I suspect -Wall on the compile line will tell you about it - (mx,mz) a complex constant, you probably mean [mx,mz], note the square brackets for an array constructor.

I only do complex <-> complex transforms, so this is new to me, but I really don't understand your arrays sizes. Why the factors of 1.5 and 3 between the arrays dimensions in the real arrays and the complex arrays? A factor of 2 I could understand, but this looks very strange.

OK, if I correct the complex constant tragedy and set integer, parameter ::  mx = 384, mz = 192     integer, parameter :: nxh =  mx, nz = mz I get the expected answers from both transforms. I haven't got time to think/learn now what the numbers should be.

p.s. I would get the complex <-> complex case sorted first, and only then add the real <-> complex extra complication

@IanBush Thank you. It was supposed to be (/ mx, mz /) to construct the array, I'm just a silly goose who forgot Fortran syntax. Funnily enough, I did have a -warn all flag in my compiler and it did not tell me anything. As for the array sizes, I figured out I needed the extra space in the complex arrays, but those particular sizes (with a 3/2 factor) are set within the DNS code I'm pulling this from. I'm not too sure why they did that either, but the important thing is that I get the same spectral and physical values.

@IanBush Also, I'm not sure what you mean by getting the complex to complex case sorted first. I'm only trying to do (ultimately) a 3D complex-to-real transform and then the reverse for the application of my pseudospectral solver

You'd probably need -Wconversion-extra (which isn't implied by -Wall) to catch that mistake. The effect of the typo is an undesired type conversion, even if it's an odd one. (I can't fault compiler writers not introducing a "surprising" check for complex constant instead of array constructor because even though it's an easy mistake it's only fraction of array constructors that can actually be miswritten as complex literal constants - not even all constant arrays of rank-1 and size-2 can be.)

For completeness, I'll share my solution to this problem as an answer. The following is a slightly altered code that indeed gives the expected output:
program fftw_test
    use,intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

    implicit none

    include 'fftw3.f03'

    ! Grid sizes
    integer,parameter :: nz = 128, nxh = 128
    integer,parameter :: mz = 192, mx  = 384

    ! FFTW Plans
    type(C_PTR) :: plan1,plan2

    ! Complex arrays
    complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), dimension(nz,nxh)    :: u_phys ! input array 
    complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), dimension(mz,mx)     :: u1_spec_2D 
    complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), dimension(mz,mx)     :: u2_spec_2D

    ! Real arrays
    real(C_DOUBLE), dimension(mz,mx) :: u1_real_2D ! 2D c2r transform target array
    real(C_DOUBLE), dimension(mz,mx) :: u2_real_2D ! 2D c2r transform target array

    ! fft planl vars
    integer(C_INT) :: rank, howmany, idist, odist, istride, ostride
    integer(C_INT), dimension(2) :: msz = (/mz,mx/)

    ! ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ !
    ! ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ !
  
    ! Create FFT plan
    rank = 2; howmany = 1
    idist = 0; odist = 0
    istride = 1; ostride = 1
    plan1 = fftw_plan_dft_c2r(rank,msz,u1_spec_2D,u1_real_2D,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
    plan2 = fftw_plan_many_dft_c2r(rank,msz,howmany, &
                                   u2_spec_2D,msz,istride,idist, &
                                   u2_real_2D,msz,ostride,odist,FFTW_ESTIMATE)


    u_phys = (0.0,0.0)
    u_phys(1,1) = (150.569261744544,1.136868377216160E-013)

    u1_spec_2D(1:nz,1:nxh) = u_phys
    u2_spec_2D(1:nz,1:nxh) = u_phys

    ! Execute FFT
    call fftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan1,u1_spec_2D,u1_real_2D) 
    call fftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan2,u2_spec_2D,u2_real_2D) 
    write(100,*) u1_real_2D
    write(200,*) u2_real_2D

    ! Destroy plans
    call fftw_destroy_plan(plan1)
    call fftw_destroy_plan(plan2)

end program fftw_test

Other than some name changes, the only difference is that I add extra space in the complex array to be transformed nz x nxh to mz x mx and I correctly make the size array an array instead of a complex number.
